# OpenLayers: Clicking close (but not exactly) on a vector to get vector features

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I have an Open Street Map and some vectors (lines) that appear over the roads. When I click on the vector I am able to get the features of that vector, however I can only do so by clicking exactly on the pixels of the vector. Is there a way I can click 'near' the vector (maybe off by a few pixels) to get the information so I don't have to be as precise?

### Code:

This is what I am currently using to get the features when I click on a vector:

```js
var displayFeatureInfo  = function (pixel, coordinate) {
            var features = [];
            map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature, layer) {
                features.push(feature); // Pushes each feature found into the array
            });

            if (features.length > 0) {   // If there are one or more features
                $("#popup").html('<object data=' + "http://URLToLoadDataFrom '/>'); // Load the data using jQuery
                popup.setPositioning('top-left');
                popup.setPosition(coordinate);
                container.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                container.style.display = 'none';
            }                          

        };

        map.on('click', function (evt) {
            var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
            displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel, coordinate);    
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build an extent out of the supplied pixel and base your feature selection using the extent instead of a single point. Thought, that means you have to use `vector.getSource().forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent` method instead of `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel`.

Check this ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/8jz2ndLf/)):

```
var displayFeatureInfo  = function (pixel, coordinate) {
            var features = [];
            //this is the offset in pixels. Adjust it to fit your needs
            var pixelOffSet = 5; 
            var pixelWithOffsetMin = [pixel[0]-pixelOffSet,pixel[1]+pixelOffSet];
            var pixelWithOffsetMax = [pixel[0]+pixelOffSet,pixel[1]-pixelOffSet];
            var XYMin =map.getCoordinateFromPixel(pixelWithOffsetMin)
            var XYMax =map.getCoordinateFromPixel(pixelWithOffsetMax)
            var extent = XYMax.concat(XYMin);
            var extentFeat= new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon([[
            [extent[0],extent[1]],
            [extent[0],extent[3]],
            [extent[2],extent[3]],
            [extent[2],extent[1]],
            [extent[0],extent[1]]
            ]]));   

            vector.getSource().forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extentFeat.getGeometry().getExtent(), 
            function (feature) {
                features.push(feature); // Pushes each feature found into the array
            });

            if (features.length > 0) {   // If there are one or more features
                console.log("features found on offset clicked",features)
               // container.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
              console.log("no features on offset click")
            }                          

        };

        map.on('click', function (evt) {
            var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
            displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel, coordinate);    
        });
```

Comment: Hi, this works great, thanks! However, the vector I'm using is currently in a group of vectors which can be turned on and off using a LayerSwitcher. When I turn the vector off and click where the vector used to be, the pop up still appears. I've tried looking at a few different ways of checking if the vector is visible but to no avail. Do you have any suggestions? 

Thanks!